# Get query result before posts are displayed?

Tags: loop, query, pre-get-posts

If I want to modify the query, I can use `pre_get_posts` filter. But what if I want to loop through the queried posts before they are ran through the `The Loop`? Is there a filter/action hook for that? I want to find out if all the queried posts belong to same `term` and then do something if they are not. Please note that creating a custom `Query` is not an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`the_posts` filter](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.2/wp-includes/query.php#L2772) to loop through the results before they get returned.

Proof of concept:

```
function test_the_posts($a) {
  var_dump($a); die;
}
add_action('the_posts','test_the_posts');
```

I am fairly certain (though I haven't tested it) that you could pretty easily break pagination and probably other things by fiddling with that, so be careful.